# Method to render rounded corners on form submit buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, rounded-corners

What I'm looking for is a clean method to round the corners of all inputs with the class "submit". I've experimented with a number of javascript techniques, but none worked well for form elements. Pure CSS would be great, but, note, the button needs to expand, and will have arbitrary text. Other methods required really ugly HTML cruft around the inputs, which I don't want.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try [CurvyCorners](http://www.curvycorners.net/) (30,100 bytes, minified) for this solution because IE browser will not make it rounded. I haven't tried adding an image though.

```
<style type="text/css">
.input-rounded-button {
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding:0 3px 0 3px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-decoration:none;
    background:#595651;

    color:#FFFFFF;
    cursor:pointer;
    font:11px sans-serif;
}

.input-rounded-button:hover { 
    text-decoration:none; 
    color:#ADD8E6; 
    cursor:pointer;
    border:1px solid #FF2B06;
}
</style>

<input class="input-rounded-button" type="button" value="SEARCH" />
```

Comment: newer IE should support the method above, if not, consider not making them rounded in IE only. I mean really, get with standards already!

Answer (score 2):

I've been using this method for a while -

http://www.oscaralexander.com/tutorials/how-to-make-sexy-buttons-with-css.html

It works pretty well

Comment: +1 Awesome.  I've used this for a while.  Pure CSS, just works.

Comment: That looks like it is for anchors, and does not seem to support vertical scaling. Or am i missing something?

Comment: You are missing something - this method can be extended to support the button element - http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/styling_the_button_element_with_sliding_doors/

Don't forget to specify a button type="submit" for IE.

I haven't found something with vertical scaling, or had the need for it.

Comment: This does NOT support form inputs, and does NOT support vertical scaling. Why the hell is this answer being upvoted? I know very well how to deal with buttons, and how to do this without permitting vertical scaling. That's NOT what I asked.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this one is the kind of workaround you are looking for.
Though it doesn't support vertical scaling. (Why the hell do you have multiline submit buttons?)

http://www.hedgerwow.com/360/dhtml/ui-css-input-replacement/demo.php

It's specialized for submit-buttons and supports a fairly reasonable browser range.

Comment: lol ... i don't have multi-line submit buttons, but if a user zooms in, i don't want the buttons to break.

Comment: Is there a mirror of this page?

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to use CSS3, the easiest way that i know is just to do this:

```
.button
{
  background-color:#f57070;
  border-radius: 10px;    //-rounding the edges, only available in CSS3-//
  font-family:arial;
  font-size:30px;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

with the html code:

```
<a href=# class='button'>...</a>
```

makes a nice red button with rounded edges.