# Rounded corners in buttons in IE

Tags: javascript, html, rounded-corners

I need to have rounded corners in buttons (input type submit), but I haven't found any JavaScript library that would do that. Currently I use http://blue-anvil.com/jquerycurvycorners/test.html to round other elements, but I doesn't round input buttons or li-elements. I prefer jQuery plugins, because I use jQuery to all other plugins and components in my app. So is there any way to round buttons in IE ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Method to render rounded corners on form submit buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782553/method-to-render-rounded-corners-on-form-submit-buttons)

Answer (score 2):

The [jQuery Corners](https://www.franklincovey.com/msb/public/javascript/jquery-corners-0.3/jquery.corners.html) plugin will fix buttons for you. It takes buttons, create anchor tags of them, and style them. This way, users without JS will only see the standard squared off button (and it will work perfectly), so it's no big loss...

I've used it myself, and it's easy to use.

Comment: I think this is the same plugin as I linked to back in july: https://www.franklincovey.com/msb/public/javascript/jquery-corners-0.3/jquery.corners.html

Answer (score 1):

You could fake it by making a rounded box with a link that submits the form. Of course, this wouldn't work with JavaScript disabled, so you'd have to watch out for that. Also, you could just use a background image that has rounded corners.

Answer (score 1):

why not make a button using css? Essentially a linked graphic? One of the sites I work on we have a method that creates a button a specific format with the supplied text and location.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [DD_roundies](http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_roundies/), its a very efficient js code that can round anything, and supports hover also.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following in my personal website (you can get the link from my profile) and it seems to work well:

- http://plugins.jquery.com/project/corners

Comment: Only problem is that it doesn't work with latest jQuery version, it requires older version...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Formwin](https://github.com/rocco/formwin) works for you - exclusively rounds form elements, but it's a jQuery plugin and works with IE8 and above.